# How to solve empty model trouble using both Ajax.BeginForm and Html.BeginForm in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, model, parameter-passing

I am new to MVC and stuck in passing modal to controller.
I have read many similar threads in SO, to no avail.

Here, I have a view for entering order details.
User will enter order item details (using ajax.BeginForm) and when he clicks save, whole order will be saved in backend (using Html.BeginForm). Ajax.BeginForm is working properly and passing + displaying records properly. But Html.BeginForm is passing model as nothing.
Here is my code ...

**My Models**

```
 public class OrderItemsModel
    {
        public string SrNo { get; set; }
        public int? ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Qty { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Rate { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    }


public class OrderModel
    {
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }

        public int? CustomerCode { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }

        //List of items selected in Order 
        public List<OrderItemsModel> ItemsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

**Extract from My View**

```
@model OrderApplication.Models.OrderModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Model.ItemsSelected = ViewBag.getlist;
}

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateItemList", "Order", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "selectedtable" }))
            {

                <h2 style="margin-left:5%;">Order Entry</h2>
                
                //Order No & Date
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNumber, "OrderNo"):
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate, "Date"):
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                //Table of entries
                <div id="selectedtable">
                    @Html.Partial("_selectTable", Model);
                </div>
                <br />
            }


               @*Main Save*@
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Order", new { order = Model, id = "loginform", @class = "justify-content-center" }))
                            {
                                <input type="submit" value="Save Order" class="btn btn-success" />
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Clear Form" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Clear", "Order")'" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**My Controller**

```
public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        public List<OrderItemsModel> dd = new List<OrderItemsModel>() ;
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveData(OrderModel order, string id)
        {

            if (order == null)      //order is always Nothing
            {
                return View(order);
            }
            if (order.CustomerCode == 0)
            {
                return View(order);
            }

            return View(order);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seeems that you only have included the input button inside your HTML form. Please, try inlcuding all fields/controls that you wish to send to the controller inside _@using Html.BeginForm_ region. Take a look at these examples, as could be useful for your case: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-HtmlBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx and 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/working-with-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform-in-mvc-3/

Comment: All fields/controls are inside Ajax.BeginForm
I had tried to close Ajax.BeginForm after Html.BeginForm (Nesting), but it did not help.

I need fields in both of them. Can you suggest a way ??

Comment: That's true, nesting Ajax.BeginForm and Html.BeginForm won't work. You should choose tu use only one of them, and place it where you have setted Ajax.BeginForm, so you that way you could cover all form fields, as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use both ***Ajax.BeginForm*** and ***Html.BeginForm***, as it won't work. Please, check this post as might be of help to decide which one you wish to choose:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1757936.aspx?When+to+use+Html+BeginForm+vs+ajax+BeginForm

If you still want to use ***Html.BeginForm***, just move the using sentence to replace your ***Ajax.BeginForm*** at the top of the page, so the form covers all fields, and the model won't be empty.